# How to create .vcd file for power analysis through xpower(xilinx 10.1) software?

Tags: verilog, xilinx, system-verilog, xilinx-system-generator

I had a verilog code. I did xpower analysis without .vcd file, with .vcd file(using simulate post route & route model)  and .vcd file (using `$dumpfile("test.vcd")` ). I am getting different result in all cases. I am explaining it below:

**1)xpower analysis without .vcd file**
Result are:

[image]
total power = 0.30292 W

**2) xpower result with .vcd file(using simulate post route & route model)**
[image]
total power=0.30361 W

**3) Xpower result with .vcd file :**
I used below lines with testbench to generate .vcd file:

```
initial begin                   
   $dumpfile("test.vcd");                  
   $dumpvars;                 
   #1000 $dumpoff;            
end
```

Result: 
[image]
    total power = 0.30184 W

Why all result in different total power? Should i need to do any correction?

Thank You

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the purpose of doing PE with VCD file? Power estimations are as it says are ESTIMATE of what the tool 'think' would be the actual value, and 2mA difference is well inside the error margin of such tools (as far as my experience says).

Comment: What is PE? if it is pwer estimation ..... Actually i am learner of Xpower analyzer of xilinx. So I did as i explained above. I want to know how to estimate power correctly using xpower analyzer?

Comment: How big is the design? (LUTs, Registers,  BlockRAM, ...).What device do you use?  The design must have a significant size, else it will be noise.

Comment: @FarhadA Doing PE without VCD files is meaningless. It's needed to calculate the FF toggle rates and to estimate the dynamic power consumption.

Comment: @paebbels i am using xilinx 10.1 with virtex 5 XC5VLX30